# Extract all tables and respective columns from long SQL Query

Tags: sql

The task I am trying to solve is to get all tables out of a long SQL query and its respective columns.

E.g.

```
SELECT 
t1.id, t1.gender, t1.name,
t2.age, t2.salary
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Wanted output:

```
{'table1': ['id', 'gender', 'name'], 'table2': ['age', 'salary']}
```

I considered using string splitting etc. getting all table names and based on the alias (if available) get the columns.
But this is getting way to complicated if there are multiple joins and maybe also `UNION`s.

Is there an available library or smart way to do that?

Comment: You need to write an sql syntax parser. Good luck with that! Questions asking us to recommend libraries are explicitly off topic here on SO.

Comment: Do you need output like table name and its columns? not the data?

Comment: @MansiRaval yes exactly I "only" need the table names and its column names

Comment: why the join is added? t1.id=t2.id? do you want to compare column name? If yes, does table1 and table 2 has same column name?

Comment: The join is added because the real queries have multiple joins where tables are connected. In this case its not about the data as said but about which columns are in the select (would be in the data set) and from which tables do they come

Comment: The question I have is, why do you need this?

Answer (score 0):

If it's only for 1 query I would advise to use MS Excel and filter on the table alias. Generate the select statement via MS Excel and you could create something like this:

```
SELECT 
'table1:', t1.id, t1.gender, t1.name,
'table2:',t2.age, t2.salary
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: We got a big query collection and queries are >100 lines each

Answer (score 0):

In case if this helps.
Take the column name from All_TAB_COLUMN and Pivot it. Still this is not exact result you want.

```
 select * from (
 select TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME in 
 ('Table1','Table2'))
 pivot
 (
  max(table_name)
  for COLUMN_NAME in ('gender','name','age','salary')
  )
 order by 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sqlglot](https://github.com/tobymao/sqlglot) to parse your query, then iterate the Expression object. For example:

```
import sqlglot
from collections import defaultdict

def populate(exp):
    result = defaultdict(set)
    for k, v in exp.iter_expressions():
        if hasattr(v, 'iter_expressions'):
            for kk, vv in populate(v).items():
                result[kk] |= vv
        if isinstance(v, sqlglot.expressions.Column):
            result[v.table].add(v.name)
    return result

sql = """
SELECT 
t1.id, t1.gender, t1.name,
t2.age, t2.salary
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.id = t2.id
"""
exp = sqlglot.parse_one(sql, dialect='sqlite')
print(populate(exp))

# print: defaultdict(<class 'set'>, {'t1': {'gender', 'name', 'id'}, 't2': {'age', 'id', 'salary'}})
```